# wp_insert_post() returning a 404 error and does not create a page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developping a front-end interface to create a certain type of post (teams with Sportspress). 
For this i'm using the wp_insert_post() function in my custom plugin.
Made a really simple form :

```
<?php 

function team_creation() {
?>

<form action="POST">

    <h3>CREER VOTRE EQUIPE</h3>

    <input type="text" name="post_title">
    <textarea name="post_content" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

    <div id="button_container">
        <input type="submit" name="button_submit" value="Sauvegarder" id='save'/>
    </div>



</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['post_title'])) {
        $my_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $_POST['post_title'],
            'post_content'  => $_POST['post_content'],
            'post_type'  => 'team',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author'  => get_current_user_id(),

        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        wp_insert_post( $my_post, true );
    } else {
        echo 'WTF BRO';
    }
}

}
?>
```

I still have a "page not found" page when submitting the form. Do you know why ? 
"404 not found, the page you are looking for has been moved or doesn't exist anymore"
Thanks !

Comment: If your custom `post_type` is newly created flash your url's. Go to settings->permalinks and hit save

Comment: I can create some of this post type from back end... You see ? And when i print the id, and that i print his title in another page, the post seems to be created...

Comment: When i do it with a post_type = 'post' it appears in the back-end list, not for others post type

Comment: So to understand, the post appears in the backend but not in the front end or the post does not inserted at all?

Comment: When i set the post_type to post, it appears everywhere. But when i set it to something else (team, event, player...), it doesn't appears anywhere. But if i print_r the title of his id, i get the title, so it might be created somewhere at list...

Comment: Hint: What is the purpose of the action attribute of a form? If you read any documentation on how to use forms it would be very obvious why you are getting a 404.

Comment: Yep was an error, changed it to a method='post' mb, it's now still doesn't creating the post....

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these before your if ISSET line.

```
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;
```

So it looks like this:

```
    <?php

        global $wpdb;
        global $post;

if(isset($_POST['button_submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['post_title'])) {
        $my_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $_POST['post_title'],
            'post_content'  => $_POST['post_content'],
            'post_type'  => 'team',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author'  => get_current_user_id(),

        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        wp_insert_post( $my_post, true );
    } else {
        echo 'WTF BRO';
    }
}

}
?>
```

And if that doesn't work try adding it in a different way using this command:

```
$table_name = 'posts';    
$wpdb->insert($table_name, $my_post, $format=NULL);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer :) The version with globals doesn't change anything, the second one makes the page loads endless :/

Comment: Oh sorry, I think i made an error with the 2nd one,  make the table name = wp_posts. so `$table_name = 'wp_posts';`

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was finally a dumb error of myself... The post_type was not 'team' but 'sp_team'. I have print_r the get_post_types() to get all type of post and saw that...

**Thanks all for the help and have a nice day/night** :)